# String as command in a pipe

Tags: unix

I have a complex `$CMD` that is generated dynamically, and I cannot control its generation (and therefore cannot change it). To simplify my question, I'll assume that it was set this way:

```
CMD=`echo 'sed -e "s/"^^"/1/g"'`
```

I want to apply this command to a pipeline. To simplify, again, I want something that would look like:

```
ls -l | sed -e "s/"^^"/1/g"
```

What should I do?

The following does not work:

```
ls -l | $CMD
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use it directly:

```
cat file | $CMD
```

Comment: @mossaab: that would be because your command is invalid. You put double-quotes nested inside other double-quotes.

Comment: The command that I put in the example is valid and works. Try this for instance: ls -l | sed -e "s/"^^"/1/g"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an array (assuming Korn shell or Bash, or possibly some others).  For example:

```
$ cmd=( 'sed' '-e' 's/^^/1/g' )
$ printf "%s\n" 'abc' '^ef' 'ghi' | "${cmd[@]}"
abc
1ef
ghi
$
```

The strings in the array `"${cmd[@]}"` correspond to what you need to pass to `sed`.  Note that by modifying your notation, you could get what you want:

```
$ CMD=`echo 'sed -e s/^^/1/g'`
$ printf "%s\n"  'abc' '^ef' 'ghi' | $CMD
abc
1ef
ghi
$
```

Part of your trouble is understanding when the shell does and does not remove quotes.  That's tricky to explain, but the error arose because you passed a double quote to `sed` (where normally the shell strips double quotes).

(Tested with `bash` and `ksh`.)

---

#### Additional constraint — CMD cannot be changed

The non-preferred (but necessary) solution is to use `eval`.  In general, `eval` is dangerous; don't use it casually.

```
$ CMD=`echo 'sed -e "s/"^^"/1/g"'`
$ echo "$CMD"
sed -e "s/"^^"/1/g"
$ printf "%s\n" abc ^ef ghi | eval $CMD
abc
1ef
ghi
$
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Unfortunately, I can't change the CMD. It is given. If there is a way to re-write the given CMD into the way you suggest, then please let me know.

Comment: @mossaab: When you have constraints like that, please say so in the question up front!  It means you might get an answer to your question that meets your requirements, even if they are a little eccentric because of the imposition of your teacher, or because of the weird system you have to fit in with.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. I already did. The question said: I want to apply THIS command to a pipeline, not a different one.

Comment: I beg to differ; that was not sufficient to make it clear that it could not be changed. Indeed, you say "to simplify my question" which indicates that what you are showing us is not what you really have to deal with.

Comment: Yes, that is clearer. But when you run into an 'it cannot be changed', then you can usually ask the people who supply the string to tell you how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: The legacy code, for which the developer is not here anymore, prints the command. This output command would then be manually selected from terminal and pasted in a pipeline. This manually copy and paste is what I'm trying to automate. It will be really helpful to get an answer to the question I asked, not to tell me to think of a different problem.

Comment: I've given you -- long ago, in the 'Additional constraint — CMD cannot be changed' section -- what you actually need to do given that you cannot change the generated command.